# Errrors while installing NLTK

Tags: python, linux, pip, nltk, gcc-warning

while trying to install NLTK by `pip install nltk` i got the following error

```
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for nltk
  Running setup.py clean for nltk
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex ... error
  Complete output from command /home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp01krw6rjpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for regex
  Running setup.py clean for regex
Failed to build nltk regex
Installing collected packages: regex, tqdm, nltk
  Running setup.py install for regex ... error
    Complete output from command /home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5loncafz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/include/site/python3.5/regex:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3/_regex.o
    regex_3/_regex.c:48:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5loncafz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/include/site/python3.5/regex" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

To solve the error `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1` i tried `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` as seen in another stackOverflow post but got the error

```
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Can someone explain what have gone wrong and what is gcc error?

P.S:- I installed virtualenv by `python3 -m venv myenv`

Comment: run `pip install --update pip`

Comment: @Anwarvic after updating pip . the errors are reduced and the error now is ```Requirement already satisfied: joblib in ./myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from nltk) (0.15.1)
ERROR: Package 'joblib' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.6'
``` i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: @Anwarvic can you explain the gcc error and why did upgrading pip solved it

Comment: I've explained the issue down below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution lies in the error as it states that:

```
Command "/home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5loncafz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pavan/Desktop/chatbot/myenv/include/site/python3.5/regex" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s1j858so/regex/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So, you're using a pip version of `8.1.1` which is too old as the current version is `20.1.1`. So, upgrading `pip` using the following command will solve your problem:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: i got the same error while working with `pip 19` which isn't too old .

Comment: Probably this issue was handled in the earlier version

Comment: ok, but the issue isn't resolved yet. see my above comment for the error

Comment: As the error states, you have python `3.5` and to use `joblib` you need at least python `3.6`.

Comment: can't i use nltk in 3.5 ? . i'm having a very bad time updating to python 3.6

Comment: Let's recap... `nltk` can't be installed as it depends on another module called `joblib` and `joblib` doesn't work on python `3.5`. So, you have to install python >= 3.5.